# Cannot call method 'bind' of undefined - Backbone LayoutManager

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, backbone-layout-manager

I don't understand what I'm doing incorrectly. I'm trying to use Backbone LayoutManager in my application and the simple code below causes the error: 'Cannot call method 'bind' of undefined'

This is my main.js file:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        jquery: 'libs/jquery',
        underscore: 'libs/underscore',
        backbone: 'libs/backbone',
        layoutManager: 'libs/backbone.layoutmanager',
        knockout: 'libs/knockout',
        templates: '../templates'
    },

    shim: {

        backbone: {
            deps: ['jquery','underscore'],
            exports: 'Backbone'
        },
        layoutManager: {
            deps: ['jquery','underscore', 'backbone'],
            exports: 'LayoutManager'
        }
    }

});

require([
    'app',
    'backbone',
    'layoutManager'
], function(App, Backbone, LayoutManager) {

        // Set all Views to be managed by LayoutManager.
    Backbone.Layout.configure({ manage: true });

    App.initialize();

});
```

Any idea what's causing this error?

Comment: Which line is causing this? Which library that exception originates from? Not sure if this is all your code, but one thing that's missing is a `shim` for Underscore (it's not AMD compliant), not sure about knockout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the version of LayoutManager that you're using, it could be that you're shimming incorrectly.  Latest LayoutManager supports AMD, so the shim is unnecessary.

As noted by @kryger's comment you received, ensure that underscore is properly shimmed.  I'm willing to bet that's your problem.

```
shim: {
    backbone: {
        deps: ['jquery', 'underscore'],
        exports: 'Backbone'
    },

    underscore: { exports: '_' }
}
```

You can also check out the documentation for configuring AMD: https://github.com/tbranyen/backbone.layoutmanager/wiki/Installation#asynchronous-module-definition-amd

^^ I've updated the above to contain the line for underscore shimming as well.